# Some applications in full screen leave an invisible gap between top of window and the top border of the screen. (win 10, multiple monitors)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, emacs, user-interface, winrar

I notice this problem with emacs, notepad++, and WinRAR. When their window is maximized to full screen, there's actually an invisible gap between the top of the window to the top edge of the screen.

This is extremely annoying because when you want to close these applications by clicking on the "X" at the top right corner, your mouse will be actually clicking the application running behind the current one, resulting in that app below closed.

I am not sure if the problem comes from some common stuff in these IDE, or if it is an OS problem. If it helps, I am running win 10 with multiple monitors. For single monitor, this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Do you perhaps have mixed DPI?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the mixed DPI, do you mean my two monitors have different scaling?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You’re right, it’s the scaling setting that matters, no the physical pixel density.

Comment: You are right! I do have different scaling on the two monitors. When I set them to be the same, this problem goes away. But my two monitors are very different in size/pixel density and setting the same scaling makes one of them unusable. Any idea how to get around?

Comment: Also, why is this a problem only for some of the apps but not for others? Sublimetext and VScode work just fine, while emacs and notepad++ have this problem?

Comment: Windows don't have a _full screen_ state (only restore, maximised, minimised, and hidden) because there was no video when windowing was designed. Programs emulate full screen by sizing their window. Hence each program will do it differently.

Comment: I can totally confirm this. Some more apps handling this the wrong way: Task Manager, MS Office 2010 suite applications, MTPutty. The bug is not reproducible with Total Commander.

Comment: The might be a workaround in case of Intel GPUs, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8imjva/ Its no silver bullet though: I have an Intel GPU, and it did not fix the problem :-(

Comment: This is still an issue with notepad++. Check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8660) to keep track of it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for years. Sometimes it was extremely annoying because I was in the middle of something and clicking on X on Notepad++ was closing my IntelliJ instance behind.

Then I checked my scale factor. it was 130. I changed it to 125 and now the problem is gone. I think this has to do with the fact that we are in a digital pixel world, and you can't divide 1 to 3 and get a fixed value, as you get 0.(3), while dividing 1 to 2.5 gives you 0.4.

Why this happens only for Notepad++, I don't know, probably it has to do with the way the author uses the underlying GUI. Maybe someone should open a defect on this.

Anyway, if anyone else has the same issue, think from mathematical perspective and try to set custom scale factors that don't give you continuous numbers as a division result. This is my observation so far.